# How is the new Google+ google IO 2012 app slide menu built?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, slide

The new Google+ app has deprecated the dashboard in favor of the slide menù. I can understand that it is done with two layouts (menù and app) that are properly hidden on demand. What I cannot understand is how is possible to use the actionbar.

Isn't it drawn automatically?

Did they deprecate actionbar as well replacing it with a custom one?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate, but I still want to know the answer! haha I don't care whose question gets answered first!

Comment: I think the other one was more on the creation of sliding menu, this one is more on the sliding of the actionbar